# Warning from PDFBox -- using fallback fonts for Symbol and ZapfDingbats

Tags: fonts, pdfbox, centos8

Running CentOS 8.0, OpenJDK 13, and Apache PDFBox 2.0.17.  I am getting these warnings:

```
... org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Symbol
... org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font ZapfDingbats
```

Any suggestions about where to find the appropriate rpm files for the Symbol and ZapfDingbats fonts?

Note that there is a bug in CentOS 8.0.1905 that creates problems with other fonts: [Missing provides in gnu-free-fonts](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16523). This was rectified temporarily by installing the missing fonts manually.

Comment: LiberationSans is the Linux replacement font for the windows fonts. See "yum info liberation-fonts". I assume that you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @M46 LiberationSans is NOT a replacement for these two fonts, this will look weird when rendering certain PDFs, e.g. with the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late, but I have resolved this by installing urw-fonts :

1- Download the rpm package from [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=urw-fonts) (For me, it was Centos 7.9)

2- Run : `yum localinstall urw-fonts-2.4-16.el7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: My CentOS is up to date and I get the following message while trying your solution: Package urw-fonts-2.4-16.el7.noarch is replaced by urw-base35-fonts-20170801-10.el7.noarch, which is already installed.